# Problem with sort order posts per current category

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, posts

This is my first question on stackoverflow.

I have problem with sorting posts. I write small plugin to sort posts alphabetically. It's work ok.
There is a code:

```
function wpb_custom_query( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() AND !($query->is_home()) ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpb_custom_query' );
```

and Query Monitor see query as:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (133,134,135,136,137,161) )
AND ((wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC
LIMIT 0, 70
```

But now I need change order posts by current category when user is.
I try it change it by adding "if" conditions when I check what category is currently loaded and get category name, next check if category name is euqal "NEWSY".
Code after modify:

```
function wpb_custom_query( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() AND !($query->is_home()) ) {

        $current_category = get_queried_object();

        if($current_category->name == 'NEWSY') 
        { 
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
        }
        else
        {
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpb_custom_query' );
```

and Query Monitor see query as:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
WHERE 1=1
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (133) )
AND ((wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC
LIMIT 0, 70
```

It works when i go to categories named "NEWSY" but problem is in parent category (133) where all posts dissapears. I don't have posts adding to parent category, all posts is assigned to child categories. It depenced by another plugin when i set permissions by category for users.
In Query Monitor I see that in query condition "wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id" has only a parent category (133) and child categories dissapear.
I don't know why it remove all chils categories from query.

I need help to fix this problem to see posts in parent categories back and still change sort order by category name.
I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: _"It depenced by another plugin when i set permissions by category for users"_ - perhaps that plugin is interfering somehow, because it manipulates the query as well? What happens when you disable this plugin?

Comment: The plugin name is "PublishPress Permissions" by "PublishPress". I switched off plugin and... posts is showed again! I compare query before and after switch off plugin and queries are the same. I switch plugin back on, and... still works that my code starts working properly. I don't know what's happened to this but restart this plugin helped to solve my problem. Thank You!

Comment: Not sure that is actually a solution ... WP initializes plugins in the order they were activated in, AFAIK - so that means PublishPress Permissions just moved to the end of the queue now. If you were to de- and then re-activate your own plugin now, I guess it would stop working correctly again? This should rather be handled via the third parameter to `add_action`, `$priority`.

Comment: I kinda newbie in wordpress then I'm sorry for strange questions. Your answer mean that I must add priority to my add_action line? Ex. "add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpb_custom_query', 1 );" ?

Comment: If it currently works or does not work, depending on the plugin activation order - then that is a pretty good indicator, that the other plugin must have added its action also using the default priority of 10. Whether you need to go higher or lower now with yours, I can't currently tell for sure, you'll have to test it. (But if the other plugin going to the end of the queue fixed your issue, that likely means its action needs to execute after yours, so yours should get added with a lower priority then.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what is wrong with your code but I suspect `get_queried_object()` is causing the issue somehow.

However, you can write your code like this in a clean way.

```php
function wpb_custom_query( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_tax( 'category' ) ) {
        if ( is_tax( 'category', 'NEWSY' ) ) {
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
        } else {
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
            $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpb_custom_query' );
```

##### Code Explanation

1. First of all I am checking to stop this customization for the backend, for this I am adding a check  `! is_admin()`
2. then I am checking if it is the main query, using `$query->is_main_query()`
3. Then I am checking if we are on category pages or not, for this, I am using `is_tax` function and passing `category` as the taxonomy name.
4. if all the conditions passed then I am again using `is_tax` but this time I am passing TERM value as well using `is_tax( 'category', 'NEWSY' )`, I am using Term name in the example, but **I will suggest you use slug or ID.** This line will let us know if we're on **NEWSY** category page or not.
5. the based on category page check I am writing an if and else statement and setting `orderby` and `order` args.

**Note:** if you are using any custom taxonomy then you'll have to change `category` to your custom taxonomy name and use term/category slug instead of term/category name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late on this, but I've had the same issue and I've been able to resolve it using `$query->set( 'suppress_filters', true );`

So your code would be:

```
function wpb_custom_query( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() AND !($query->is_home()) ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'suppress_filters', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpb_custom_query' );
```